# Можно ли обучить нейросеть программированию?

Tags: нейронные-сети, любой-язык

Насколько технически выполнимым является создать нейросеть, обученную создавать код на каком-то ЯП?
Я не имею ввиду, что эта нейросеть обязана будет создавать изящный код на языке типа C++. Важен сам факт того, что она сможет кодить на примитивном ЯП. Не могу правильно сформулировать, но я имею ввиду создание нейросети, которая будет создавать код для какой-то одной цели. Например, для создания ОС.

Comment: для начала нужно научить нейросеть понимать заказчика :D

Comment: нет ничего невозможного, вопрос в том, сколько времени учить и какие ресурсы нужны

Comment: Хорошо, сформулирую вопрос немного по-другому

Comment: какбы программированием занимается человек, думаю для начала нейросеть должна не уступать ему)

Comment: Конечно можно. У нас много таких нейросетей на зарплате.. Причём с не самым оптимальным каналом ввода информации - оптическим.

Comment: в 2018 сложно выполнимым)

Comment: Если серьёзно, нужно придумать, как формализовывать ТЗ, как построить процесс обучения. Не нужно пытаться начинать с таких проектов, как ОС. Попробуйте научить НС закодировать алгоритм сортировки. Вообще, на данный момент ближайшее, что есть — машины, проверяющие корректность математических доказательств.

Comment: Вообще, вместо создания ОС (это сложный и муторный процесс) лучше сделать переводчик программ с одного языка на другой. Проблема заключается лишь в том, что даже людям это сложно сделать, по-этому прийдется немало потрудиться, чтобы такое написать. А так неплохая идея, я был бы рад, чтобы кто-то такое написал (а вообще сам бы хотел принять в таком проекте участие)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Пусть стоит задача для нейросети, создать объект с двумя полями и одним методом по требованию заказчика. И что? Принципиальных ограничений нет. Научить хреново кодить нейросетку сможет даже студент, если пару месяцев посидит над задачей.

Другое дело, отлаживать, выверять код, находить более оптимальную архитектуру, делать чтобы всё работало и устраивало заказчика - это слишком долгий процесс. Ещё лет двадцать машины не смогут конкурировать с программистами, по моей экспертной оценке.

Сегодня написать один нейрон, обдумать его логические связи, задать вес под нужную задачу - это довольно трудоёмкий процесс. Есть пока что более простые задачи, решение которых сулит большие деньги, чем кодинг для заказчика. Проще говоря, развитие нейросеток ограничивает экономическая целесообразность - в первую очередь будут написаны нейросетки, такие что:

**P/E = max**, здесь P - гипотетическая прибыль, E - расходы на написание.

И если расходы на написание становятся вообще не прогнозируемы, такие проекты откладываются на неопределённое время.

ЗЫ [Вон рабочий прототип](https://vc.ru/31732-neyronnaya-set-kotoraya-verstaet-sayty-po-kartinke).

Answer (score 2):

Я могу себе представить НС способную генерировать бессмысленный код на каком-либо ЯП, который может быть скомпилирован без ошибок. Также можно попробовать реализовать такую НС для простых односложных задач. Но я не представляю себе НС, способную написать ОС. Это уже из разряда искусственного интеллекта (ИИ) и пока это, по-моему, невыполнимая задача.